# Maximum displacement of weighted basket attached to spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

In the following question (no longer homework):

A basket of negligible weight hangs from a vertical spring scale of force constant 1500 N per m. a) If you suddenly put a 3.00 kg adobe brick in the basket, find the maximum distance that the spring will stretch. b) If, instead, you release the brick from 1.00 m above the basket, by how much will the spring stretch at its maximum elongation?

I have a few questions:

1. By conservation of energy, we can calculate the a) answer to be 3.92. I was able to figure that out. However, why is it not sufficient to just ensure that the displacement x satisfies mg >= kx, i.e. that the force of gravity is large enough to stretch the object x meters? Is it because we are stretching a weighted spring instead of an ideal one?
2. In a) the solution manual arbitrarily sets the final height of the brick-spring system to 0. Intuitively, why is this type of action allowed? I was able to derive it algebraically for this particular scenario of a) but not in b). I don't really get *intuitively* why it's okay to do this type of thing in general, beyond the particular case where the final height of the basket is indeed 0. The issue in my head is that gravitational potential energy is dependent on height from the ground.

[image]